# Filter results by multiple rows from a Key Value table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to filter my query results by each row of a key value table I made, of which's data will be dynamic and come from the UI.

I have forms that have associated form inputs, which have associate form input details.

Say my form results that looks like this (Where Name and Age are FormDetail.FieldNames):

```
Form Name | Name   | Age
------------------------
Form 1    | Jason  | 19
------------------------
Form 2    | Martha | 25
------------------------
Form 3    | Jason  | 20
------------------------
Form 4    | Tim    | 30
```

Users should be able to filter these results by multiple combining filters, where all conditions that they pass need to pass (IE not OR, it should be AND). So if they pass in the filter { Name : "Jason", Age : "19" } the results should only show Form 1.

Here is my query so far:

```
DECLARE @KeyValue Table (
 KeyString VARCHAR(MAX),
 ValueString VARCHaR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @KeyValue (KeyString, ValueString)
VALUES ('Name', 'Jason')
INSERT INTO @KeyValue (KeyString, ValueString)
VALUES ('Age', '20')

SELECT * FROM Form
INNER JOIN FormInput 
   ON Form.FormID = FormInput.FormID
INNER JOIN FormDetail 
   ON FormInput.FormDetailID = FormDetail.FormDetailID
INNER JOIN @KeyValue KeyValuePairFilter 
   on KeyValuePairFilter.KeyString = FormDetail.FieldName 
  AND KeyValuePairFilter.ValueString = FormInput.TextValue
```

However, this is returning results where either of the filter conditions are met, not when ALL of them are met (in my example, it would return Form 1 and Form 3 instead of just Form 1).

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I'd prefer not to use dynamic SQL but if that's the only option I could use it. I'm using SQL Server 2014. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your DDL statement is incomplete? What is Form, What is FormInput? Is Jason 20 or 19 ? Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Form inputs are the collection of values in the form, so a user filled in a for with the "Name" key being "Jason" and the "Age" key being "19", and another user filled in another form with the "Name" key being "Martha" and the "Age" key being "25", etc. So it's possible for a forms to have the same form input values (like Jason in my example). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT f.FormID
FROM Form f JOIN
     FormInput fi
     ON f.FormID = fi.FormID JOIN
     FormDetail fd
     ON fi.FormDetailID = fd.FormDetailID JOIN
     @KeyValue kv 
     ON kv.KeyString = fd.FieldName AND
        kv.ValueString = fi.TextValue
GROUP BY f.FormID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @KeyValue);
```

This version just returns `FormID`.  You can add more columns to the `SELECT`/`GROUP BY`.  Or use `JOIN`, `EXISTS`, or `IN` to fetch all the columns from one or more tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon! That's exactly what I needed.